# I have to double every command? (V 2.76)

Tags: workflow

Recently, my PC crashed after I upgraded from Windows 7 to 10. I was able to restore my PC back to Windows 7, but since then I have had an issue with having to repeat everything within Blender. A perfect example would be with the text tool. If I add a text object that should say "Blender", when I'm done typing as such, I have an end result of "Blende". The same goes for loopcuts. I have to stop one short, or I have one too many. However, and this is the weird part, if I use the screencast keys addon, problem solved. No need to repeat anything, everything is as it should be. I have refreshed defaults, and gone so far as uninstalling and reinstalling Blender. Any ideas?

Comment: @Zeffi, sorry for the delayed reply, I didn't see a notification on this thread. I'm using Windows 7 home. I had been using 10 when my PC went down (before the upgrade all was perfect). I did try refreshing Blender with factory defaults as suggested, but I still have to enable screencast keys to work smoothly which can be distracting at times.

Comment: Hi Timaroberts, the best practice on this site is to answer our follow-up questions directly by editing your original Question (plentty of room to elaborate). I see you have edited the question a little bit, that's great. You can then delete the comments here below by hovering over the end of the comment and you'll see a small X .

Comment: @Italic_'s answer covers the most likely remedies, but if there are things about that answer you don't understand you can add a comment to his answer and he will probably elaborate.

Comment: If things were working fine before you upgraded to windows 10, it seems to me that the issue is not with blender, but with the drivers for the video card. Go to the website of your card manufacturer and download drivers compatible with windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

The loop cut example sounds like normal behavior, so I don't know what you're experiencing. If you could upload a video demonstrating the problem, maybe that could help us diagnose.

Until then, try refreshing blender with factory defaults. You can do this by removing your user prefs. By default, these are stored in:

Windows

> C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\%VERSION%\config\

Linux

> ~/.config/blender/%VERSION%/config/

Remove or rename `config` folder and blender should start up with factory defaults.

A simpler way is to start blender from the terminal (CMD) with the `--factory-startup` flag to bypass any and all config files (there are multiple locations blender searches for user prefs).

Windows `blender --factory-startup`

Linux `./blender --factory-startup`